# Passing HTML Text when button is pressed using javascript

Tags: javascript, button

I have a rails app that creates a standardized card-box for every  db record. It creates a button in each box so there are multiples of the same button class. I want to pass the text card-box to send an AJAX request. So each box has a different variable to send. Currently when I click any button it only passes the last element in the card-text array. I'll include a screenshot to show what I'm talking about. Below is the JavaScript snippet that handles the button click.

```
let track = document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark');
let getPackages = document.getElementsByClassName('card-text');
let tNumber = "";
for(let i=0; i<track.length; i++){
    track[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        for (let j=0; j<getPackages.length; j++){
            console.log(i);
            console.log(j);
            if (i == j){
                console.log(tNumber = getPackages[j].innerText);
                tNumber = getPackages[j].innerText;
                console.log(tNumber); 
                sendRequest(tNumber);
            }
        } 

    });
}
```

[image]

Entire card html:

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
          <svg class="bg-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="placeholder: Thumbnail">
            <title>Package</title>
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"></rect>
            <image href="https://volumeintegration.com/wp-content/uploads/PackageIcon.png" width="100%" height="225"/>
          </svg>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">
              <%= package.tracking %>
            </p>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between alight-items-center">
              <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark" id="trackButton">Track</button>
                <%= link_to 'Delete', package, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-outline-dark"%>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show sample HTML for one of the cards, including the button? It should be straightforward to associate a button with its card-text on click.

Comment: why do you have the for var j loop in there?  all you're doing there is calling getPackages[i] if you use i===j

Comment: Posted the html code. Honestly I am very new to the world of JavaScript so I'm just trying to figure things out as I go along.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out I used the .closest() method then got the child

```
let track = document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark');
let tNumber = "";
for(let i=0; i<track.length; i++){
    track[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
           let parent = track[i].closest('.card-body');
           tNumber = parent.getElementsByClassName('card-text')[0].innerText;
           console.log(tNumber);
           sendRequest(tNumber);  
    });
}
```